# Limit result of subtraction to a minimum of zero

Tags: r, constraints, min

I have a vector 'x' where values ranges from 0 to 1, e.g. `x <- c(0, 0.5. 1)`. I'm subtracting, say, 0.5 from 'x':

```
x - 0.5
```

The result of `x - 0.5` will range from -0.5 to 0.5. However, I want to constrain the minimum of the result to 0, i.e. the new range will be 0.5 to 0, any previously negative numbers will now be coerced to 0.

Is there a simple way of doing this? I've looked for "constrain" and "limit" and such. I assume I could probably bash it into shape with `if` or filtering but I was hoping there was an elegant function that hasn't surfaced in my searches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See `?pmax`.

```
pmax(0, x - 0.5)
```

I.e. pick whichever is larger -- that would be zero if `x < 0.5`.